# Is it possible to create a movable rows in table view as the normal state? (see attached photo)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How can I create a movable rows for my table view as the normal state , like in instagram manage filters page:

[image]

Currently I use the usual method to edit rows with edit button(using moveRowAtIndexPath) and the three lines to move rows appearing to the right and I can drag the rows, but I need to create it this way(the above pic), please help me figure this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the thing that you want is to have the editing by default you just have to add this line:

```
  [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]
```